# Installing requirements

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda

I'm new in python and anaconda . I have some cods and I need a lots of requirements for run , how can I install that packages? The requirements includes Python 3.3 or later numexpr numpy 1.9 or later pandas 0.15.2 or later scikit-learn 0.16 scipy 0.15 or later six C/C++ compiler ipython (optional) seaborn (optional) Tnx

Comment: When you install Anaconda for Python 3.x, I think all those packages will come with it.

Comment: Tnx for your comment . Yep I install it again

Answer (score 0):

It's a good practice to first create a virtual environment using the `virtualenv` command, and then activate it  with `source <environment_path>/bin/activate`.

After loading the virtual environment, you should be able to use `pip install -r requirements.txt` to install the requirements listed in the file.

Comment: Tnx for your comment although I run "virtualenv" it's error is this virtualenv is not recognized as an internalor external command operable program or batch file

Comment: `conda install virtualenv`

Comment: It's better to tell you my question in this way, I have survival-support-vector-machine zip which I downloaded it in github.com/tum-camp/survival-support-vector-machine so I wane run it for my data. but unfortunately I don't know to run it even for it's data....!!now is it possible to help me?

Answer (score 0):

Anaconda comes with its own package manager `conda`. You should probably use that to install extra packages.

With the possible exception of a C/C++ compiler (although it includes `cython`, which needs a compiler IIRC), all packages that you need come with anaconda. You'l find a list of included packages [here](http://docs.continuum.io/anaconda/pkg-docs).

Comment: tnx for you comment. when I wane run this cod "conda create -n ssvm python=3 --file requirements.txt" it has this error which " Error can't open file :requirements.txt

Comment: Does the file `requirements.txt` actually exist in the directory where you run the command?

Comment: yes, it does. it's in my package which I wane run it. I take copy from the package then past it on the anaconda file

Comment: @sonia11 Either you made a spelling mistake with the name of the `requirments.txt` file in the `conda create` command, or there is some kind of permissions problem with the `requirments.txt`.